# Sort in C# don't save the place

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a class named move
it has a field named val of type int
And I have a list of moves named mlist

I wrote this

```
mlist.Sort((b, a) =>
    {
       if (a.val > b.val)
           return 1;
       else if (a.val == b.val)
           return 0;
       else
           return -1;
    }
    );
```

at first my list have two objects that both has .val = 0
when I sort the list the place of these two object is changed. But I don't want to this to happen. What can I do?

Comment: Why you don't want these two elements to swap?

Comment: It's defined behaviour: [This implementation performs an unstable sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).

Comment: Because the first 0 in the list is a real 0 but the second one isn't. it is based on my program. but anyway there should be a way.

Comment: @HansKesting: thanks. Is there any stable sort available on list in C#?

Comment: @Masoud - yes, see the answer by Dervall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) performs a quicksort which is an unstable sort.

If you want a stable sort you could use the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) method which is available through LinQ

Using `OrderBy` in your example would be assuming that `mList` is a `List<>`

```
mList = mList.OrderBy(a => a.val).ToList();
```

Should you desire the reverse ordering, the method is called `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Can I use it in List? I don't know a lot about LinQ

Comment: You can use it in any `IEnumerable` which also includes `List`

Comment: The only difference is that OrderBy is not in-place but it creates a new collection.

Comment: @JesseJames: you can't do Sort().OrderBy() because Sort() doesn't return `List<T>` in the first place, also it is useless...

Comment: So it is too time consuming if it create a new collection

Comment: Here's the one-liner: `mList = mList.OrderBy(x => x.val).ToList();` of course it is more memory expensive than Sort(), but you won't probably even notice the difference...

Answer (score 2):

You should use orderBy:

```
   MyComparer comparer=new MyComparer();
   mlist=  mlist.OrderBy(p => p, comparer).ToList();



  public class Comparer : IComparer<YourObject>
    {


        public int Compare(YourObject a, YourObject b)
        {

            if (a.val > b.val)
                return 1;
            else if (a.val == b.val)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Hans Kesting said sorting is unstable.
Read about stable sorts here http://www.csharp411.com/c-stable-sort/